# Do improvement token bonuses count as skill bonuses when determining the highest bonus to apply to a test?

Tags: eldritch-horror

When one has an asset that grants +2 skill and one that grants +1, the effective bonus is not additive. Rather, we apply the highest bonus. My questions is: do the bonuses from improvement tokens count as similar "+" bonuses or are they separately added as "additional die rolls" are. Namely, if I have a +1 improvement token on my strength and I hold an asset that grants me +1 to strength, is my effective bonus +2 or merely the best "+" bonus (ie +1 in this case)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Improvement tokens are neither a "skill bonus", nor "additional dice", they provide dice in a separate step.

> When an investigator resolves a test, he performs the following steps:
>
> 1. **Determine Dice Pool**: The investigator determines the number of
>      dice he will roll. This number is his **DICE POOL**.
>
> •  He starts with a number equal to the skill being tested.
>   •  He adds or subtracts the test modifier (the number that follows
>   the skill icon on the effect).
>   •  If he has an Improvement token for the skill being tested, he
>   adds the Improvement token’s modifier.
>   •  He may use **one** effect that provides a bonus (for example “Gain
>   +3 Will”). If multiple effects provide a bonus, he uses only the
>   highest bonus.
>   •  He adds any “additional dice” he gains from effects that apply.
>   Additional dice are cumulative and are in addition to other
>   effects

Source: [Reference Guide](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/eldritch-horror/EH01%20Reference%20Guide.pdf), "Tests" (page 11)

**Everything**, except "skill bonuses" stacks.
Only the effects worded as "gain +X [some skill]" are skill bonuses.
All other effects are not skill bonuses, and stack.